# How do I handle git asking me to remove untouched files?

Tags: version-control

A while ago, I cloned the Drupal repo. Today, I attempted a pull only to find out that I'm being asked to remove most, if not all, of the `core` directory to prevent overwriting. This happened to me once again about a month ago and I fixed it by removing the `core` directory prior to pulling, but obviously I can't remove the directory every time I pull. How can I fix this once and for all?

EDIT: git output:

```
➜  dev-drupal git:(10.1.x) ✗ time gl
remote: Enumerating objects: 28, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (25/25), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
remote: Total 28 (delta 8), reused 17 (delta 8), pack-reused 3
Unpacking objects: 100% (28/28), 29.22 KiB | 1.33 MiB/s, done.
From https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal
   d3d1d05dfa..3c8128a0ac  11.x       -> origin/11.x
Updating 2090b606ea..65212de44c
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    composer/Generator/Builder/DrupalCoreRecommendedBuilder.php
    composer/Metapackage/CoreRecommended/composer.json
    composer/Metapackage/DevDependencies/composer.json
    composer/Metapackage/PinnedDevDependencies/composer.json
    core/MAINTAINERS.txt
    core/assets/scaffold/files/default.settings.php
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/ckeditor5-dll.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/ar.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/ast.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/az.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/bg.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/bn.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/ca.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/cs.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/da.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/de-ch.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/de.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/el.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/en-au.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/en-gb.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/eo.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/es.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/et.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/eu.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/fa.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/fi.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/fr.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/gl.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/he.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/hi.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/hr.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/hu.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/id.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/it.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/ja.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/km.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/kn.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/ko.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/ku.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/lt.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/lv.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/ms.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/nb.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/ne.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/nl.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/no.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/pl.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/pt-br.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/pt.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/ro.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/ru.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/sk.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/sl.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/sq.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/sr-latn.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/sr.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/sv.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/th.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/tk.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/tr.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/tt.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/ug.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/uk.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/ckeditor5-dll/translations/ur.js
    core/assets/vendor/c
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/horizontal-line/translations/uz.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/special-characters/translations/hr.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/table/translations/sl.js
    core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/PathChangedHelper.php
    core/modules/block_content/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php
    core/modules/file/tests/modules/file_test_views/config/optional/node.type.file_test.yml
    core/modules/file/tests/modules/file_test_views/config/optional/views.view.test_file_to_node.yml
    core/modules/file/tests/modules/file_test_views/config/optional/views.view.test_file_to_user.yml
    core/modules/file/tests/modules/file_test_views/config/optional/views.view.test_file_user_file_data.yml
    core/modules/file/tests/modules/file_test_views/config/optional/views.view.test_node_to_file.yml
    core/modules/file/tests/modules/file_test_views/config/optional/views.view.test_user_to_file.yml
    core/modules/file/tests/src/Kernel/Views/RelationshipNodeFileDataTest.php
    core/modules/node/tests/src/FunctionalJavascript/NodeDeleteConfirmTest.php
    core/modules/system/tests/modules/path_changed_helper_test/path_changed_helper_test.info.yml
    core/modules/system/tests/modules/path_changed_helper_test/path_changed_helper_test.routing.yml
    core/modules/system/tests/modules/path_changed_helper_test/src/Controller/TestController.php
    core/modules/views/tests/src/FunctionalJavascript/RedirectAjaxTest.php
    core/tests/Drupal/KernelTests/Core/Routing/PathChangedHelperTest.php
    core/tests/Drupal/Tests/Core/Routing/PathChangedHelperTest.php
    core/themes/claro/css/components/dropbutton-noscript.css
    core/themes/claro/css/components/dropbutton-noscript.pcss.css
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
git pull  0.11s user 0.24s system 16% cpu 2.032 total
```

I have edited root composer.json but other than that, I haven't touched any files.

EDIT: Output of `git status`:

```
➜  dev-drupal git:(11.x) ✗ gst
On branch 11.x
Your branch is behind 'origin/11.x' by 47 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   sites/default/default.settings.php

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .DS_Store
    .idea/
    .lando.yml
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/horizontal-line/translations/uz.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/special-characters/translations/hr.js
    core/assets/vendor/ckeditor5/table/translations/sl.js
    core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/PathChangedHelper.php
    core/modules/block_content/src/Routing/
    core/modules/file/tests/modules/file_test_views/config/
    core/modules/file/tests/src/Kernel/Views/RelationshipNodeFileDataTest.php
    core/modules/node/tests/src/FunctionalJavascript/NodeDeleteConfirmTest.php
    core/modules/system/tests/modules/path_changed_helper_test/
    core/modules/views/tests/src/FunctionalJavascript/RedirectAjaxTest.php
    core/tests/Drupal/KernelTests/Core/Routing/PathChangedHelperTest.php
    core/tests/Drupal/Tests/Core/Routing/PathChangedHelperTest.php
    core/themes/claro/css/components/dropbutton-noscript.css
    core/themes/claro/css/components/dropbutton-noscript.pcss.css
    modules/.DS_Store
    modules/contrib/
    modules/custom/
    sites/default/files/
    sites/default/settings.php
    vendor/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: This sounds unusual. More information is needed.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: What does `git status` say before pulling? Git seems to be accurately reporting local changes.

Comment: That's the Drupal 11 branch you've got there isn't it, is that what you're expecting?

Comment: @unusedspoon yes it is.

Comment: @cilefen the thing is, I have only edited root composer.json.

Comment: Asking again: What does `git status` say before pulling? What actual Git command are you typing that then causes this?

Comment: Adding the output to the question because it's too long to add here. I'm typing only `git pull`.

Comment: What file system is the disk using?

Comment: Note: The following is destructive, but should work. Use with care: `git reset --hard HEAD; git clean . -f`, then you can run `git pull` after. The two commands will reset your repo to exactly the same as the branch in the repo, by reverting any changes that have been made, and removing any files that aren't tracked by Git.

Comment: @cilefen it's using apfs.

Comment: @Jaypan this worked, but will I have to do it every time? What is wrong here? I never had to do this before. Also, please make your comment an answer.

Comment: I don't know how this would have come about, but it shouldn't happen every time I don't think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is destructive, but should work. Use with care: git reset --hard HEAD; git clean . -f, then you can run git pull after. The two commands will reset your repo to exactly the same as the branch in the repo, by reverting any changes that have been made, and removing any files that aren't tracked by Git.